# How to pass a parameter to controller action from view in rails through link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
<%= link_to "Connect", {controller:"home", action:"connectTo"}, id: "btny" %>
```

This is my `link_to` helper in view.

I want to attach a parameter in this `link_to` tag so that I can get it in the action `connectTo`. I'm unable to find correct syntax or way to do it, and unable to understand some answers I found on stackoverflow.
How can I achieve this?

```
def connectTo 
  #here i want to get the parameter i pass from link_to from view...
end
```

Comment: have you tried `<%= link_to "Connect", {controller:"home", action:"connectTo", my_param: 'foo'}, id: "btny" %>`, and then `params[:my_param]` ?

Comment: It is also not working. I tried your code and saved params[:my_param] in @myVar and displayed it on connectTo view, and got no output.

Comment: what url have you got when you click on the link ?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/home/connectTo

Comment: something's wrong. You should have an additional `?my_param=foo` at the end of the url

Comment: <%= link_to "Connect", {controller:"home", action:"connectTo", my_param: "foo"}, id: "btny" %> is working now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Do not use camel case in variable names and method names in Rails. That's not a convention and will bite you later.
2. Use named path when you can, instead of manually assign controller and action.

For your question, suppose your named path is `home_connect_to_path`, then

```
link_to "Connect", home_connect_to_path(foo_param: 'bar_value')
```

The link will look like

```
http://localhost:3000/home/connect_to?foo_parms=bar_value
```

Then get it in controller

```
def connect_to
  foo = params[:foo_param] # 'bar_value'
```

Comment: How do i make a named path for my controller and view?

Comment: Once you have defined such path in `routes.rb`, you can run `rake routes` in command line to see the names of all paths.

Comment: Can you please tell how to define a path in routes.rb?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using named paths?

Comment: Maybe there it is, I have not used that before. But, if a path doesn't have name, it must be undefined in routes.rb. If not in routes.rb, you can't reach it. So you can't jump over routes.rb.

Comment: I am not familiar with what a "named path" is and a simple google search isn't giving me an immediate answer. Any ideas?

Comment: is there a way to do it without showing in the url?

Comment: Hello Billy Chan, I want to pass parameter to controller but I'm not using any form_tag or form_for. Its just a plain web page. Can I do this without form?

Comment: from api.rubyonrails.org > Be careful to sanitize the path parameter if it is coming from a web page. send_file(params[:path]) allows a malicious user to download any file on your server.